# cancel event mousedown in javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown

I'm doing a drag and drop and when the draggable object passes certain limits that I have set to the screen I want to return it to its original position.

My problem is that if the onmousedown event is active the object don't return to its original position until onmouseup event is called.

Is it possible to cancel or stop mousedown while it's running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the mousemove event when a specific condition is met:

```
function trackMouse(e) {
    if (e.pageX > 200 || e.pageY > 200) {
        // stop execution (event continues to run)
        // alternatively, to detach this event:
        $(window).off('mousemove', trackMouse);
    } else {
        $('#output').html(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY); 
    }
}

$(window).on('mousemove', trackMouse);​
```

[Demo (JSLint)](http://jsfiddle.net/yYVM5/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should be using the onmousemove-event to see if you've reached the limit, but are using the onmousedown, <strike>which as you say won't fire before you release the mouse button.</strike> which is is fired only once as you press the mousebutton

Comment: onmousedown triggers as soon as you press the button, it's onmouseup that triggers once you release the button.

Comment: I'm using " .bind('drag',function( event) " from jquery to see if the object reached the limit. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may find this [jquery.event.drag](http://threedubmedia.com/code/event/drag) plugin useful. It allows you to cancel the drag while it is in progress. From its docs:

> drag
>
> This event fires after "draginit" and "dragstart" every time the mouse
>   moves. The handler can return false to stop the drag interaction and
>   go straight to "dragend" and also prevent any "drop" events. If
>   dragging multiple elements (from "draginit"), this event will fire
>   uniquely on each element.

Answer (score 0):

@Voitek Zylinski: your solution works, but I finally found this solution that is better in my case:

```
$(document).trigger("mouseup");
```

Thank you.